# calculate difference between two time()

Tags: php, mysql, time

I am storing the time of the record entry in MySQL using the time() function of php.The entry is stored in a field type 'int'

Is there a SQL query I can run to get the total number of records in the last 24 hours?

Thanks for your time,

Sunil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `id`
  FROM `table`
 WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) > FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `table` 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`entrydate`) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: You probably mean `FROM_UNIXTIME` instead of `FROM_UNIX_TIME`.

Comment: @alex: I get what i deserve...shame on me :)